# Can't connect to SVN repository

Tags: svn

I'm having trouble checking out a repository from my server. I have the repository created in /home/evolving/public_html/svnrepos/tdo.

Here's what happens:

```
james-skidmores-macbook-pro-2:tdo james$ svn checkout svn+ssh://evolving@evolvingprocess.com/svnrepos/tdo
evolving@evolvingprocess.com's password:
stdin: is not a tty
svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://evolving@evolvingprocess.com/svnrepos/tdo'
```

I've also tried changing the path to svn+ssh://evolvingprocess.com/public_html/svnrepos/tdo. Why is it not able to find the repository?

Is there a way to basically ask a repository what its front-facing path is?

Comment: What in the world is "epssh"?

Comment: seems to be "error powered secure shell"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://evolvingprocess.com/home/evolving/public_html/svnrepos/tdo/
```

Usually, svn+ssh uses the full path unless you've set up a wrapper program to take care of that for you.